# What if I don't want to see reduced ads?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising

The ads on Stack Exchange are friendly and non-intrusive. I also would like to support the site with more ads (even if it doesn't make much difference).

May I have an option to turn off reduced ads?

Comment: This option already exists in your Preferences while editing your profile.

Comment: Definitely [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275687/171886).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences and turn on ads.